# what is the smallest $m$ that $ax+by=c$ has non-negative solution for all $c>m$?

Tags: number-theory

Of course, $a$,$b$,$c$,$m$,$x$,$y$ all are integers.

For example, in the case of $a=3$ and $b=7$, we have $m=11$, as $12=3\cdot 4 + 7 \cdot 0$, $13 = 3\cdot 2 + 7 \cdot 1$, $14=3 \cdot 0 + 7\cdot 2$, $15 = 3 \cdot 1 + 12$..., and then $11$ itself can't be slit as required.

But is there a formula for such $m$?

Comment: See [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).